# How to Diagnose App Pool Issues

Tags: iis, c#-4.0

I have a large web app that runs on our two live servers. Part of our server side C# code calls a third party app to do a task for us.

That task works most of the time, but at a certain point it stops working until the AppPool is recycled.

This all happens in w3wp.exe, so I can see it running in process monitor like this (when it is not working),

```
Thread Create
Access the file PreviewGenerator.exe
Hive unloaded (this is the registry)
Thread Exit
```

And like this when it is working,

```
Thread Create
Access the file PreviewGenerator.exe
Process Start
Does heaps of stuff with PreviewGenerator.exe including reading / writing / registry, etc.
Process Exit
Hive unloaded
Thread Exit
```

How can I debug what is going on in my AppPool and why starting a separate process is not working some of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best thing to do was to create a separate app pool for my application in IIS and set an upper limit for the amount of RAM it could use. Also I found it useful to turn on the 'Generate Recycle Event Log Entry' items under the app pool settings.

You can then go to the system event log and filter out the items with a source of 'WAS' to understand what is going on in the app pools, when they are restarting and when they stop from being idle etc.

I think the main problem in our case is that the IIS box was running out of memory. Tuning the app pools and adding some extra RAM seems to have solved it.